# find url parameter with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing my website (html code) with curl:

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/product.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now i want to find a specific `<span>` with an `<a>` the a tag contains an `href` with a parameter. Is it possible to find this parameter (`[eventUid]=22`) with preg match? I want to save the `22` (id) that comes from a database to a variable using PHP.

Example:

```
<span><a title="mytitle" href="http://example.com/products.html?tx_example_pi1[eventUid]=22">example</a></span>
```

```php
if (preg_match('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', $content, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[2];
} else {
    echo 'Nothing found!';
}
```

At the moment I only found links with this preg search.

Comment: just a suggestion: why not use parse_str.. its much faster..

Comment: Doing that with regular expressions looks terribly complicated. I'd suggest to simplify and use [DOM functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) instead.

Comment: if you found the link, why dont you simply split the string with '=' and get the id (22)?

Comment: i do not find the link what i am searching for...i will try parse url

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions to search through HTML is error prone; it's better to use XPath for that:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xp->query('//span/a[contains(@href, "[eventUid]=")]') as $anchor) {
    if (preg_match('/\[eventUid\]=(\d+)/', $anchor->getAttribute('href'), $matches)) {
        echo $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you mean with $content? the url of my website? And foreach ($xp->query('//span/a[contains(@href, "[eventUid]=22")]') is not possible because the number is dynamic this would be better foreach ($xp->query('//span/a[contains(@href, "[eventUid]=")]') ?

Comment: @Jim You already have `$content` coming from `curl_exec()`. I've updated the XPath and updated the code inside the loop.

Comment: thanks, but he doesnt go inside the foreach :( var_dump($xp) returns this object(DOMXPath)#179 (0) { }

Comment: @Jim Well, it works [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IABtBw), which is the HTML you gave earlier.

Comment: hmm yes your example works...it seems to be a problem to parse the website http://codepad.viper-7.com/E0rccz

Comment: $content = curl_exec($ch); // output string(14909)
$doc = new DOMDocument;
var_dump($doc);
object(DOMDocument)#178 (0) { } 
$doc->loadHTML($content);
var_dump($doc);
object(DOMDocument)#178 (0) { } 
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
var_dump($xp);  
object(DOMXPath)#179 (0){ }

Comment: @Jim $doc->saveHTML() should show you what it managed to parse.

Comment: $doc-saveHTML($content)  gives me string(14909) via var_dump and with echo the whole website

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27858/discussion-between-jim-and-jack)

Comment: @Jim Well, the website doesn't contain any links with `[eventUid]`; see [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NL3mfm).